# SELinux ignoring /etc/sysconfig/selinux directive

Tags: linux, server, selinux

I'm running SELinux on CentOS 6.5. In `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` I have set `SELINUX=permissive`. But everytime the system starts, `sudo getenforce` shows SELinux as `Enforcing`. What could be causing it to go into enforcing mode?

`sestatus` shows the following:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `sestatus` and see what it says for "Mode from config file". If it says "permissive" there, then something else sets enforcing -- either during the boot-up process, or via the kernel command line (look for `enforcing=1` in `/etc/grub.conf`).

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question to include the output of `sestatus`. It shows that the mode from the config file is `enforcing`. I also verified grub.conf does not have `enforcing=1`. Is there another config file it could be using?

Comment: Can you verify that your `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` is a symlink to `/etc/selinux/config` (that's the file that actually matters)?

Comment: I was actually just checking that as you were typing it. There was no symlink. I created it, modified the config file again to set it to permissive, and rebooted. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For everybody who came across this, I had to learn it the hard way...

If you have ever used '`sed`' in order to modify the selinux file in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` - this will destroy the symlink to the original `/etc/selinux/config` file

https://github.com/ghoneycutt/puppet-module-selinux/issues/24